# How to plot to two separate boxplots on the same axes?

Tags: r, subset, boxplot, axes, continuous

I’ve currently got two separate boxplots for “pollutionData.csv” data.
One for the PM2.5 levels at 12 noon when rain = 0 and another one for 12 noon when rain > 0.

The code I’ve used is:

```
dat$constant <- 0
boxplot(PM2.5~CONSTANT, data=subset(dat, RAIN == 0 & hour == 12))
boxplot(PM2.5~CONSTANT, data=subset(dat, RAIN > 0 & hour == 12))
```

My question:
How do I make these two boxplots appear on the same axes.

Any help would be appreaciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the dat$CONSTANT <- 0, this is for just 1 boxplot. The tilda (~) is used to specify separation. For example, if your RAIN values are 0/1 , you can do:

```
dat = data.frame(RAIN=sample(0:1,200,replace=TRUE),
hour = sample(1:12,200,replace=TRUE),
PM2.5=runif(200))

boxplot(PM2.5~ RAIN > 0,data=subset(dat,hour == 12),names=c("RAIN==0","RAIN>0"),xlab="")
```

[image]

If there are values other than 0/1 for RAIN, do:

```
dat = data.frame(RAIN=sample(0:5,200,replace=TRUE),
    hour = sample(1:12,200,replace=TRUE),
    PM2.5=runif(200))

sub_dat = list(
"RAIN==0"=subset(dat, RAIN == 0 & hour == 12)$PM2.5,
"RAIN>0"=subset(dat, RAIN > 0 & hour == 12)$PM2.5
)
boxplot(sub_dat)
```